# A question about prayer

Tags: salat, sunnah, islamic-scholar, obligation, tashahhud

Salam I've got a question about prayer, the tashahhud/at-tahiyat part. When I was saying the Attahiyyaatu lillaahi wassalawaatu part I didn't say lillaahi. Does that invalid my prayer if I miss a word? Also because I didnt know that I was meant to say that word (i forgot).

Answer (score 1):

Walaikumussalam. Missing a word in tashahhud **changes** the real meaning of it. Since tashahhud is one of the **wajib**(obligatory) acts of prayer, So you have to do your prayer again.

Comment: but what if you've been saying it wrong in all prayers? Does that mean all your prayers were invalid?

Comment: @fatima you should at least repent from that mistake and do it correctly once you've known the correct way.